# pass PHP echo result to javascript function and display in view?

Tags: javascript, php, json, post

I'm trying to pass the JSON results of a PHP API call to a function which will display the results in the view.

`script.js` function

```
function ajaxProductsSearch() {

    products.empty();
    preloader.css('visibility', 'visible')

    // Issue a request to the proxy
    $.post('test.php', {
            'search': searchBox.val()
        }

        function($results) { // pass $results from test.php?
            if ($results.results_count == 0) {

                preloader.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                message.html("We couldn't find anything!").show();
                return false;
            }

            $.each() { // code to display in view?

                // var html = ''; 
                // products.append(html);
            };

            preloader.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }, 'json');
}
```

Basically, you enter a search term in textbox in the view and `script.js` will post the string to the `test.php` script which will then run the API query request and display the results by `echo $results`.

Comment: What's the issue...?

Comment: You missed a comma between function($results) and rest of $.post..

Comment: What is it doing instead of making the AJAX call? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 1):

This will display your results initially so you can proceed with your development.

```
function($results) { // pass $results from test.php?
    if ($results.results_count == 0) {
        ...
    }

    // toString won't provide a nice output, but it will
    // show your results object. Handling the results is 
    // dependent on the structure of your object.
    message.html($results.toString());
}
```

I suggest replacing message with a jQuery object pointing to a container element of your search results.

E.g. `<div id="search-results"></div>` and `$("#search-results").html($results)`.

It's stylistically better to return a JSON object from your PHP and parse that with your javascript, but I'm assuming you're just returning a string with your results currently.

I advise you to look up these functions:

- PHP `json_encode()`
- jQuery `$.parseJSON()`

Comment: `$results.results_count` implies that `$results` is an object. But `message.html($results)` requires it to be a string of HTML. It can't be both.

Comment: It's definitely a string, `$.post` returns strings. In js you can extend the String prototype, I'm assuming Brett has a `String.prototype.results_count = ...` somewhere.

Comment: He has `'json'` as the `dataType` argument to `$.post()`. That tells it to call `JSON.parse()` on the response before calling the callback function.

Comment: @Barmar My mistake, I didn't see that. I've updated the code accordingly and added a comment explaining why I can't provide a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I finally got it to work, below is the code if anyone is interested. I wasn't sure if I could pass `$results` from `test.php` to a function in `script.js`. `console.log($results)` helped confirm that the API query was successful and stored in `$results`.

```
function ajaxProductsSearch(){

    products.empty();
    preloader.css('visibility','visible');

    // Issue a request to the proxy
    $.post('test.php', {
        'search' : searchBox.val()
    },
    function($results) { // pass $results from test.php?

        console.log($results);
        if($results.results_count == 0){

            preloader.css('visibility','hidden');
            message.html("We couldn't find anything!").show();
            return false;
        }

        $.each($results.results, function(i,item) { // code to display in view?


            var html = '<a class="product" data-price="$ '+$results.results[i].price+'" href="'+$results.results.url+'" target="_blank">';

            console.log($results.results[0]);
            // If the product has images
            if($results.results[i].images && $results.results[i].images.length > 0){
                html += '<img alt="'+$results.results[i].name+'" src="'+ $results.results[i].images+'"/>';
            }

            html+='<span>'+$results.results[i].name.substr(0, 20)+'</span></a> ';
            products.append(html);
        });

        preloader.css('visibility','hidden');

    },'json');  
}
```